# AH00128: File does not exist - index.html no loading

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, apache2, apache-log-files, httpd

I want `/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/index.html` to load.  Currently another page is loading instead.

`/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/index.html` is displaying in green font on the cli.

Error log shows

```
[Wed Dec 07 10:57:54.646257 2022] [core:info] [pid 27408] [client 43.130.66.225:57739] AH00128: 
File does not exist: 
/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/files/, referer: binance.com
```

I don't understand why `/files/` is being looked for when `/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/` is the directory to use which matches the webserver configuration file.

```
    [Neptune@0rcan0mic conf.d]$ cat thepowerhousemethod.org.conf
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName thepowerhousemethod.org
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html/
            ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/thepowerhousemethod.org-error.log
            CustomLog /var/log/httpd/thepowerhousemethod.org-access.log combined
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    
            <Directory "/var/www/thepowerhousemethod.org/public_html">
            DirectoryIndex index.html
    #       AllowOverride All
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    #AllowOverride None
    #Allow from all
            </Directory>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thepowerhousemethod.org
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
```

any suggestions? Self hosted bare metal server

Answer (score 1):

the webserver configuration file domain.com.conf was missing

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com
systemctl restart httpd
```

site loads!